# Does glEnable slow things down?

Tags: vb.net, opengl, opentk

I'm just currently writing my various routines. What I am doing is at every routine that say needs blending, I enable blending at the beginning and disable it at the end. Is this a bad thing?

For example:

```
Public Sub DrawQuad()
        GL.Enable(EnableCap.Blend)
        GL.BlendFunc(BlendingFactorSrc.SrcAlpha, BlendingFactorDest.OneMinusSrcAlpha)

        GL.Begin()
        GL.End()

        GL.Disable(EnableCap.Blend)
End Sub
```

I have this, but I might call this 500 times in the same go, which means blending will get enabled/disabled 500 times. Will this greatly effect performance compared to just enabling once, drawing 500 quads and than disabling?

Comment: Yes, changing state is always more expensive than not changing state.  But worrying about a few extra `Enable`/`Disable` calls when you're still using `Begin`/`End` is like blowing out a candle while your house is burning down.

Comment: Yeah I realize Being/End is deprecated, but I can understand it, it works, there seems to be more info about it and I don't have a problem with performance yet, I'm only doing basic 2D stuff, so if it isn't broken I won't fix it.

Comment: That was the point I was trying to get across - if you're not having performance issues, why are you optimizing?

Comment: I'm writing A LOT of these functions and wanted to know if this could lead to some serious side effect in the future, but as you say its minor which what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Premature optimization is the root of all evil!

- As bcrist pointed out in the comments, if you're looking to optimize your OpenGL code, do **learn the programmable pipeline**. It's faster, more customizable, less reliant on magical function calls, and generally more awesome.
- In general, optimize your big problems first, then get specific.
- The best way to find out the answer to your question is to **profile your code**. OpenGL drivers are implemented by the hardware vendors for each device. Yes, calling any function repeatedly when you could call it just once will cause a performance hit, but how does that stack up against the rest of your code?

The take home point is admittedly annoying - your question is misguided and the "answer" isn't going to answer your actual question about calls to `glEnable`. You should optimize many things before you start looking at small functions like that.

For example, once you get the rest of your design sorted out and you realize that grouping together certain drawing routines by `glEnable` is even *possible* in your program, much less doable without incurring more overhead than it eliminates, *then* you might look into doing something to get rid of them.

Comment: Not really an answer